# how does Spark handle more memory than its capacity

Tags: apache-spark

Say my Spark cluster has `100G` memory, during the Spark computing process, more data (new dataframes, caches) with a size of `200G` are generated. In this case, will Spark store some of this data on Disk or it will just `OOM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark only starts reading in the data when an action (like `count, collect or write`) is called. Once an action is called, Spark loads in data in partitions - the number of concurrently loaded partitions depend on the number of cores you have available. So in Spark you can think of `1 partition = 1 core = 1 task`.

If you apply no transformation but only do for instance a `count`, Spark will still read in the data in partitions, but it will not store any data in your cluster and if you do the `count` again it will read in all the data once again. To avoid reading in data several times, you might call `cache` or `persist` in which case Spark will try to store the data in you cluster. On cache (which is the same as persist(`StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY`) it will store all partitions in memory - if it doesn't fit in memory you will get an OOM. If you call persist(`StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK`) it will store as much as it can in memory and the rest will be put on disk. If data doesn't fit on disk either the OS will usually kill your workers.

In Apache Spark if the data does not fits into the memory then Spark simply persists that data to disk. Spark's operators spill data to disk if it does not fit in memory, allowing it to run well on any sized data. Likewise, cached datasets that do not fit in memory are either spilled to disk or recomputed on the fly when needed, as determined by the RDD's storage level.
The persist method in Apache Spark provides six persist storage level to persist the data.

```
MEMORY_ONLY, MEMORY_AND_DISK, MEMORY_ONLY_SER 
(Java and Scala), MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER 
(Java and Scala), DISK_ONLY, MEMORY_ONLY_2, MEMORY_AND_DISK_2, OFF_HEAP.
```

The OFF_HEAP storage is under experimentation.

Comment: I thought it would still spill to disk with persist memory only. No so?

Comment: Note that all concurrently loaded partitions have to fit into memory, or you will get an OOM.  Not well worded.